# How to create an inline function that modifies a variable in Python?

Tags: python, function, methods, lambda, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def do_action(self):
        self.method()
```

and I want to instantiate it as follows:

```
some_var = False

def bar():
    # Modifies existing variable's value
    global some_var
    some_var = True
foo = Foo(bar)
```

how do I do that without having to define the bar() method?
I've tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
foo = Foo(lambda: (some_var := True))
```

When I do this the IDE tells me there's an identifier expected. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thank you to those who answered, however I didn't really find exactly what I needed. Not sure if it's the best practice, but I ended up using python's `exec` and it works as intended:

```
foo = Foo(lambda: exec("some_var = True"))
```

Comment: You might need to include more code.  What's `some_var` actually supposed to be?  Your example `bar` is a no-op since `some_var` is a local variable.

Comment: Assuming `some_var` is a local/global variable, and if you really, *really* want to do something like this, you can add `nonlocal some_var` or `global some_var` (which every is appropriate) to `bar`. But this question really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you elaborate on why you want to add a method to an object that modifies a local/global variable?

Comment: @Samwise It's supposed to change the value of an existing global variable. I thought the comment in the `bar` would suffice but I'll add in a declaration.

Comment: oh that's extremely gross, you'd have to use `globals()` to be able to modify that inside a lambda.  Don't do it IMO.  Global variables are bad enough without doing unnecessarily weird shenanigans like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to have `bar` be able to modify an instance attribute, have `bar` take the `self` parameter so `do_action` can tell it which instance it's operating on.  You can't do a variable assignment inside a `lambda`, so use `__setattr__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
        self.some_var = False

    def do_action(self):
        self.method(self)


foo = Foo(lambda self: self.__setattr__("some_var", True))
foo.do_action()
print(foo.some_var)  # True
```